# Iframe click with javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have this javascript code:

```
function start1(dis,www){
    var visina = screen.availHeight;
    var content = '<a href="#" id="showRtb"><div id="showRtbn" style="position: fixed;text-align:center;left: 0px;width: 225px;height: 80px;top: 50%;z-index: 9999999;background: #E81515;cursor: pointer; border-radius:5px; margin-left:-15px;"> <iframe src="https://domain.com/hotel/2" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe></div>   </a>          <div id="rtb" style="width:100%; height:100%; opacity:0; position:fixed; box-sizing: border-box; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:99999999; display:none; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)"><iframe src="'+www+'" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe><div id="hideRtb" style="background:#fff; cursor:pointer; top:15px; right:15px;  z-index:9999999; position:fixed; border-radius:25px;"><img style="width:50px; height50px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/QqlcQwu.png"></div></div>';

var newNode = document.createElement("DIV");  
newNode.innerHTML = content;
document.body.appendChild(newNode); 



   var rtb = document.getElementById("rtb"),
  timer = null;

document.getElementById("showRtb").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (rtb.style.opacity != 1) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    rtb.style.display = "block";
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      rtb.style.opacity = +rtb.style.opacity + .10;
      if (+getComputedStyle(rtb).getPropertyValue("opacity") >= 1) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 30)
  }
});

document.getElementById("hideRtb").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (rtb.style.opacity != 0) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setInterval(function() {
      rtb.style.opacity = +rtb.style.opacity - .10;
      if (+getComputedStyle(rtb).getPropertyValue("opacity") <= 0) {
        rtb.style.display = "none";
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, 30)
  }
});




}
```

and as you can see, I create a link inside the body with id `showRtb` and inside that an iframe with content, but when I click it doesn't work, doesn't want to show div with id `rtb` ...

When I change the content so instead of an iframe I post an image, then it works well, but now with the iframe it doesn't work. Why? What is the problem?

So, I want when I click on `showRtb` to open div with ID rtb ...

UPDATE:

```
var content = '<div id="showRtb1" style="position: fixed;text-align:center;left: 0px;width: 225px;height: 80px;top: 50%;z-index: 9999999;cursor: pointer; border-radius:5px; margin-left:-15px;"><iframe src="https://domain.com/hotel/2" name="myiFrame1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe></div><a href="#" id="showRtb"><div id="showRtb" style="position: fixed;text-align:center;left: 0px;width: 225px;height: 80px;top: 50%;z-index: 99999999;cursor: pointer; opacity:0; pointer; border-radius:5px; margin-left:-15px;"></div></a><div id="rtb"><iframe src="'+www+'"  name="myiFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe><div id="hideRtb"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/QqlcQwu.png"></div></div>';
```

Comment: You have no access to an iFrame with content from another server. Also that iFrame has no access to parent or scripts in the parent. Also your HTML is invalid.

Comment: No, I dont want access, I just want when click on that iframe ID to open other div with ID rtb ...

Comment: You mean the button you added isn't working?

Comment: An iframe in [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), what kind of sourcery is that?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh no, link dont working, I need when I click on link showRtb to show div with id rtb... when I post image instead iframe inside link id=showRtb then everything works fine

Comment: Your click inside the showRtb is absorbed by the iFrame and not sent to the function

Comment: how to change that ?

Comment: Don't use an iFrame inside a link

Comment: but I need to show some design from my server to other website , thats why I use iframe inside that...

Comment: @AleksPer but how is the iframe supposed to show something if it is inside a link?

Comment: I update my queston, so I try to put an div in the front but dont work again, click evnt fired but rtb not show

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
var content = '<a href="#" id="showRtb"><div id="showRtbn"> <iframe src="https://domain.com/hotel/2" name="myiFrame1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe></div></a><div id="rtb"><iframe src="'+www+'"  name="myiFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe><div id="hideRtb"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/QqlcQwu.png"></div></div>';
```

To be something like:

```
var content = '<div id="showRtbn"><iframe src="https://domain.com/hotel/2" name="myiFrame1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe></div><a href="#" id="showRtb">Show RTB</a><div id="rtb"><iframe src="'+www+'"  name="myiFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe><div id="hideRtb"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/QqlcQwu.png"></div></div>';
```

Remove the iFrame from within the anchor tags (`<a>..</a>`) and you can set its containing `<div>` as hidden. **NOTE:** I've removed your styles. You should consider moving them into a stylesheet

JS:

```
document.getElementById("showRtb").addEventListener("click", function() {
  rtb.style.display = "block";
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

Comment: Probably because I've removed the styles you had added...?

Comment: Now I see it, but when I click nothing happend... so click on showRtb dont open rtb

Comment: Make sure you either have the styles in your HTML or you remove the style checker in the action listener. I've updated the code with how the JS may look like (without the style check)

Comment: I update my question with new code, now I try to put an div with opacity:0 in the front but again dont work...

Comment: Add `console logs` in the on click listener and first confirm if the click event gets fired. Then I'd suggest you first simplify your code to make sure the basic logic works (in this case, click event and display/hide iframe `div`), after which you can add everything else

Comment: Comment out your click listener, copy paste the example in the answer, add `console.log('clicked')` and see if that works